# on click show divs with specified ids or classes and fade out all other divs

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fade, out

I got a problem  i want to show all divs with a specified class oder id name and hide all others on page. This is my Link when i click on

```
<a href="#" title="Test">Filter Button action</a>


<div id="Test" class="simpleCart_shelfItem item Test" data-ng-repeat="item in items" size-column="" style="margin-bottom: 20px; zoom: 1; opacity: 1;">
        <div class="item_image"><img ng-src="http://paypalinstant.com/images/purse1.jpg" src="http://paypalinstant.com/images/purse1.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></div>
        <h2 class="item_name ng-binding" ng-bind="item.name">Item Name 1</h2>
        <div class="item_description ng-binding" ng-bind="item.description">The term purse originally referred to a small bag for holding coins. In British English, it is still used to refer to a small coin bag. A "handbag" is a larger needed accessory, that holds items beyond currency, such as a woman's personal items and emergency items to survive on. American English typically uses the terms purse and "handbag" interchangeably. The term "handbag" began appearing in the early 1900s. Initially, it was most often used to refer to men's hand-luggage. Women's accessory bags grew larger and more complex during that period, and the term was attached to the women's accessory.[1] Handbags are used as fashion accessories as well as functional ones.</div>
        <div style="margin-top:10px;">
              <div>  <p style="width:50%; float:left; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 3px; color: #529092; " class="item_cat ng-binding" ng-bind="item.cat">TEst</p>                 <p style="font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 3px; color: #529092; " class="item_subcat ng-binding" ng-bind="item.subcat">Sonnenbrillen</p>
</div>  
        <button class="item_add btn btn-xs btn-success" style=" margin-top: -8px;  "> In den Warenkorb<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> </button> 
        <span class="item_price ng-binding" style=" font-size: 23px; margin-bottom: -9px;  "> €99.20</span>
    </div>
```

on it i will have all Divs with id or class name "Test" to appear and fade out the rest of the  divs which dont have the choosen div or classname.

Comment: `$("div#test").show()` and `$("div:not(#test)").hide()` ? change `show()` and `hide()` with whatever you need, like `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()`

Comment: how to put thisd in an onclick evenet in the Link ?<a href=""onclick="('div#Test.show')('div:not(#test).hide')">TEst</a> ???

Comment: wrap it with a function and call the function onclick, see here -> http://jsfiddle.net/A7uVu/

Comment: do you know how to make it dynamically for several ids or classes @BeNdErR `<a href="#" onclick="filter('Test');">Test</a>` this way ?